# String manipulation in a loop and then reading it

Tags: python, string

I'm sure it is simple, but after googling for a hour (new to python), I'm still not sure what to google to fix my issue :( you can see from my current code and the desired results as to what I am trying to achieve!

Thx
Matt.

Code :

```
usernames = ['joe', 'john', 'fred']

joe_image = 'c:\aaa\blahblah.jpg'
john_image = 'c:\aaa\foobar.jpg'
fred_image = 'd:\aaa\1234.jpg'


for z in usernames:
    print z
    y = z + '_image'
    print y
```

Results :

```
joe
joe_image
john
john_image
fred
fred_image
```

Desired Results

```
joe
c:\aaa\blahblah.jpg
john
c:\aaa\foobar.jpg
fred
d:\aaa\1234.jpg
```

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? He's shown us what he has tried, and he needs help on a particular concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something called a [Dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
lookup_path = {'joe': 'C:\whatev', 'john':'C:\else'}
for z in usernames
    print lookup_path[z]
```

Comment: Bingo, thx that worked. Will have a bit of a play with dictionaries.  With dictionaries can you have multiple items for example per username? example. joe : item1, item2,  fred : item1, item2 ? or is that a different fucntion?

Comment: yes, but, that's a little more complicated. You would have: 

`lookup={'joe':['item1','item2']}`

So, you get a list when you do `lookup['joe']`

Answer (score 0):

You're printing a string that happens to be the name of your variable, not the variable itself.

You might want to completely rethink your program and use a dictionary instead.

```
users = {'joe':'c:\aaa\blahblah.jpg','john':'c:\aaa\foobar.jpg','fred':'d:\aaa\1234.jpg'}
```

Then you can look up with `users['joe']` to get `'c:\aaa\blahblah.jpg'`.

If you really want to refer to variables by name with strings though, it is possible with `eval`. This is very bad practice, though, and should always be done with care and hopefully never at all.

Comment: He asked because he didn't know what *sort* of structure he needed to google.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can have TWO arrays of single dimension or you make your initial array two dimensional instead of single dimension

So either you would have

User_Names(x,y,z)
and
User_Photos(x,y,z)
where User_Photo(x) is for User_Name(x) 
where User_Photo(y) is for User_Name(y) etc

or you would have
User_Info(NameColumn, PhotoColumn)

And then UserInfo(1 , 0) May be "Joe"
And then UserInfo(1 , 1) May be "c:\aaa\blahblah.jpg")

And

And then UserInfo(2 , 0) May be "John"
And then UserInfo(2 , 1) May be "c:\aaa\foobar.jpg")

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would to be use namedtuple you pay the price of losing brevity for clarity.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Pair = namedtuple('Pair', ['name', 'filename'])

them = [ Pair('joe', r'c:\aaa\blahblah.jpg'),
        Pair('john', r'c:\aaa\foobar.jpg'),
        Pair('fred', r'd:\aaa\1234.jpg')
        ]

for who in them:
    print who.name
    print who.filename
```

Gives

```
joe
c:\aaa\blahblah.jpg
john
c:\aaa\foobar.jpg
fred
d:\aaa\1234.jpg
```